# Monitor Acer KG271: keeps disconnecting watching Netflix

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, netflix, extended-desktop

I recently bought a new **Acer KG271 monitor** (it's a pretty new item, on the market since the first half of 2017 - [full specs here](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/GB/content/model/UM.HX1EE.027)). I connected it with the HDMI cable provided in the box and immediately tried to extend my laptop screen on the new one.

Two are the issues here:

1. If I try to set my laptop as first main screen, and having the Acer as secundary...
2. ... and if I try to watch Netflix (now, **anything** on Netflix)

it will go black, will try to scan the other sources (HDMI2, VGA...), and end up showing the "no source found" like message.
The thing is that it isn't a real disconnection because the open windows on the Acer don't come back to the laptop.

Has anyone a clue of what's going on?

---

### EDIT (few moments later)

Sorry guys, it was a test I didn't run before: with the VGA connection **both issues are solved**.
But it's still pretty annoying that I can't use the HDMI connection...

Comment: So, are you asking a question, or not?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear: yes, the question in my first post is still on: what's going on with the HDMI connection?
My edit was just to try to add a piece of the puzzle...